# Android adding new xml and class

Tags: android

I'm adding a new xml layout and I couldn't connect it to java class.

Process;

- I'm adding a new xml layout
- I'm adding a new java class
- Editing AndroidManifest.xml
- adding setContentView(R.layout.second_layout); to my java class.

I try to return main_activity with using button.I don't know problem is code or xml and class pages connections. Is there anything else I'm going to do?

second_layout_java.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class second_layout_java extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
        //
        Button show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_button);

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml //I'm adding a new activity for new xml

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.app.second_layout"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIGER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It sounds like you have the basics covered but you need to post how you are trying to "connect it to java class". Show the code of how you are trying to call that `Activity` and maybe the `onCreate()` of that `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first problem is that you don't switch `Activities` by just changing the `layout` file with `setContentView()`. Sure, you can change the content view this way but its not typically a good idea and not practical in most situations. You need to use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to start a new `Activity`.

So assuming that the `Activity` you are trying to "return" to is called `MainActivity`, your `onClick()` would look more like this

```
 show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // create the Intent object
            Intent i = new Intent(second_layout_java.this, MainActivity.class)  
            // call the startActivity() function to start the Actiivty
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In this situation, if you haven't finished your previous `Activity` by calling `finish()` on it, specifying in your `manifest.xml` to not keep history, or in some other way, then you could simply call `finish()` in your `onClick()` and you would be brought back to your previous `Activity`.

To follow Java naming standards, this class name should be mixed-case with the first letter of each word being capitalized and get rid of the underscores. This isn't necessary but is the standard. So it might look something like

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity
```